# Using a Multi Select to call another list in a SharePoint workflow SPD 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow, infopath2010

I have a form for users to fill out to request information.  One of the fields in the form is to select Regions to send it to:  Global, North America, Europe, Asia.  There want to further select by country in each region.  1-N countries with 1-n people in each Country.

The form is sent for a approval, once the approved an email is sent to the submitter to let them know it is approved (easy).  A separate email is sent to each person in the selected Regions\Countries (May want to send to All of the Americas region or do something like just England, Canada, and Australia or to Everyone if Global is selected.)

A person can be a contact for multiple countries, or not for a country they are in.  People move frequently, so AD Groups aren't not a good choice.

I had tried making a list were all the emails were grouped by Region, but it would only work if I selected One region ie Europe, but not if I selected 2 regions, ie Asia and Europe.

I am thinking I have to do some kind of For loop to loop throw my Contact list, but haven't seen any good examples of this.  I am not sure it can be done using SharePoint Designer and I might have to try with a custom Visual Studio solution, but the client doesn't really want to go that route if at all possible.

Comment: Out of the box workflows in SharePoint are pretty limited. I think you may have hit upon one.  I assume you've tried using "Workflow Lookup for a User" from the Select Users dialog and used the Region field from your list to look up the users in the other.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Yes, I have tried Using the workflow look up.  Everything I have seen on it says that they will really return only one row of data.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're in 2010, you're limited to building a custom action in Visual Studio that you'll deploy to the farm and access via SPD, a VS workflow, or maybe one of the 3rd-party solutions like K2/Nintex.